# Odoo 8.0 (OpenERP) Creating Custom Module - How to save data to model?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

I'm new to Odoo and I read already many tutorials and documentations about that topic.

I just want to know the basic how to save data to your model in your frontend view.

So I have a template form with some inputs:

**templates.xml**

```html
<form action="/seatReservation/post" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="name" required="True" placeholder="Your Name*"/>
  <input type="text" name="email" required="True" placeholder="Your Email*"/>
  <button>Insert</button>
</form>
```

And I have a controller with the action:

**controllers.py**

```
@http.route('/seatReservation/post/', type='http', auth="public", methods=['POST'], website=True)
    def thankyou(self, name, email):
        val = {'name':name, 'email':email}
        reservation_obj = http.request.registry['academy.reservations']
        reservation_obj.create(http.request.cr, http.request.uid, val, http.request.context)
```

But I get an error because `http.request.cr` cannot be found. What am I doing wrong, I just want a simple form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found a solution, I don't know if its the smartest way but it works:

```
@http.route('/seatReservation/post/', type='http', auth="public", methods=['POST'], website=True)
def thankyou(self, **kwargs):
    reservation_obj = http.request.env['academy.reservations']
    reservation_obj.create(kwargs)
```